# What is the difference between in passing command doSomething and doSomething() to a Tkinter Button?

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to know why  `myBtn = Button(text="btn", command=doSomething)` is different from  `myBtn = Button(text="btn", command=doSomething())`.

When I create a button and add the command doSomehting,  `myBtn = Button(text="btn", command=doSomething)`, I get expected behavior - it does something.

But when I create the button and add the command `doSomething()`,  `myBtn = Button(text="btn", command=doSomething())`, it get unexpected behavior - it calls `doSoemthing()` and button clicks do nothing.

**Why does this happen?**

```py
from tkinter import *
import datetime
import random

def printRandNum():
    random.seed()
    val = random.randint(1, 1000)
    print(val)


top = Tk()
now = datetime.datetime.now()

top.title("Test Window")
top.geometry('800x600')

name = Label(top, text="Alex", fg="Orange", font="monospace 36 bold", anchor="w", width=50)
theDate = Button(top, text="Click here for the date", command=printRandNum)

theDate.pack(side=BOTTOM)
name.pack(side=LEFT)
top.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are writing `doSomething, myBtn = Button(text="btn", command=doSomething` you are passing the `doSomething` **function** as a parameter, so that the `Button` can call it when it's clicked. When you are writing `myBtn = Button(text="btn", command=doSomething())` you are passing the **return value** of the function as a parameter, this implies that the `Button` object can't call the `doSomething` function because it only gets its return value.